# Entity Framework 5.0 RC - Package Manager command 'add-migration' fails due to supposedly missing configuration type

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, visual-studio-2012, database-migration, entity-framework-5

Using Entity Framework 5.0.0 RC/EF 5.x DbContext Generator for C#/Visual Studio 2012 RC/.NET 4.0, I'm trying to enable automatic migrations in my project. I've run `enable-migrations` in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> enable-migrations
No classes deriving from DbContext found in the current project.
Edit the generated Configuration class to specify the context to enable migrations for.
Code First Migrations enabled for project Test.
```

As you can see, it didn't automatically detect my DbContext derived type, but I solved this easily enough by entering the name of this type in the generated code file, `Migrations/Configuration.cs`.

However, the next step, the Package Manager Console command `enable-migrations` fails due to not finding the migrations configuration type added by the previous step.

```
PM> add-migration Initial
No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Test'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).
```

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:** I found that I could specify the name of the configuration type with the parameter `-ConfigurationTypeName`:

```
PM> add-migration -ConfigurationTypeName Test.Migrations.Configuration Initial
The type 'Configuration' is not a migrations configuration type.
```

This still doesn't work, but at least it elucidates why `add-migration` bails, i.e. it thinks `Test.Migrations.Configuration` isn't a migrations configuration type. Does anyone have a clue as to why it isn't accepted, given that it was generated by enable-`migrations`? See the generated code below for reference (UserModelContainer derives from DbContext):

```
namespace Test.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using Test.Models;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<UserModelContainer>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(UserModelContainer context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in your solution? Btw. you mentioned you are using DbContext Generator - migrations are only for code first.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Ah, that's probably it, I'm doing model first come to think of it. I don't know Entity Framework that well, and I've always designed the model visually first. I'll look into the code first approach, and see if I have to switch to that. I don't quite understand what difference it makes if the code is generated from a model though.

Comment: I'm not sure if this limitation wasn't removed from 5.0RC but previous versions threw error when you try to migrate model which wasn't created with code first. Anyway that error should be thrown later - your problem is probably not related to that.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Yeah, the uncertainty regarding the actual cause of the error is really frustrating :( Btw, the solution is one project only.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I tried the code-first approach now, defining the database model and context classes myself, and I get exactly the same error :(

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm targeting .NET 4.0 (yes, I wrote originally 4.5, but that was by mistake), as add-migration works if I target 4.5. Unfortunately Azure doesn't support 4.5 :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I had installed Entity Framework 5.0.0 RC while targeting .NET framework 4.5. Due to deploying to Windows Azure, I found I had to target .NET 4.0 instead. I don't know the intricacies of NuGet, but it seems that the EF package installed for .NET 4.5 didn't work properly with my 4.0 targeting project.

After reinstalling the EF NuGet package, while targeting my project at .NET 4.0, everything works well.

Comment: Here's the NuGet bug if you're interested in adding your vote: [Dynamically change package target when multi-Targeting](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/989)

Comment: Isn't the labyrinth is ghastly. Aghhh.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

Package Manager Console Host Version 2.8.50926.663

Problem still there. Thanks for detailed description and solution.